# angular 2 typescript asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm having an issue setting up Angular 2 with Typescript via ASP.Net MVC 5.

The problem is the line in my .cshtml

```
System.import('../assets/ts/boot')
```

fails , unless I append a

```
.js
```

So this works:

```
System.import('../assets/ts/boot.js')
```

This applies to every import, so for instance

```
var app_component_1 = require('./app.component');
```

fails, but this works

```
var app_component_1 = require('./app.component.js');
```

This situation is basically untenable from a compilation point of view - everything resolves if I edit the transpiled .js files, but I can't do this after every compilation.

Can anyone help?

Here are my csproj settings:

```
<TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
<TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
<TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
<TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
<TypeScriptOutFile />
<TypeScriptOutDir />
<TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
<TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
<TypeScriptMapRoot />
<TypeScriptSourceRoot />
<TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
```

Here is my config settings:

```
> <script>
>     System.config({
>         packages: { 'app': { defaultExtension: 'js' } }
>     });
>     System.import('app/boot')
>             .then(null, console.error.bind(console)); </script>
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your problem is in your System.config, not in your csproj settings. Update your question and add your config.

Comment: Do you wanna try system.js instead of common.js  ?

Comment: I've updated the question above

Comment: I've managed to get this working but its not an ideal solution. If you add a Home\add folder to the project root and put the scripts in there it works.

It seems as though SystemJS always applies Home to the path, and therefore wont add the default extension to file types.